# Invalid block tag: 'render_field', expected 'empty' or 'endfor'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-templates

I'm getting this error message from django, and don't understand why, especially because I use this exact code to render forms in other templates in my project.  This is the full template:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-8">
    <form action="{% url 'great_songs:new_playlist' %}" method="POST">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {% for field in form %}
        <div class="form-group">
          {{ field.errors }}
          {{ field.label_tag }} {% render_field field class+="form-control" %}
        </div>
      {% endfor %}
      <button name=submit>submit playlist</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Assuming that you-re using `django-widget-teaks` did you load the tag library in your template? `{% load widget_tweaks %}` ?

Comment: Wow - that's it.  Feeling like a fool - thanks!

Comment: Brilliant lol, helped me today as well! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using django-widget-tweaks
please be sure you do this:

Install using:

```
pip install django-widget-tweaks
```

Add to the dependencies :

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'widget_tweaks',
]
```

and finally load in template:

```html
{% load widget_tweaks %}
<html>
...
```

For more info look the doc [here](https://pypi.org/project/django-widget-tweaks/),
And now you can do whatever you want to customize

Comment: I had to add {% load widget_tweaks %} directly into the included template.